# How to convert this queryto Laravel ORM

Tags: laravel, eloquent, orm

Hi guys I'm new learner Laravel.
I can not  convert belowed SQL query, please help me to solve the problem.
SQL query is worked fine just I want to convert it Laraver Eloquent ORM.

```
select distinct u.*, d.user_id, r.region_name from users as u 
                left join devices as d on d.user_id = u.id
                left join region as r on r.region_id = u.region_id 
                where d.user_id is null and u.`role` = 3
                order by u.id asc
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here you go:

```
DB::table('users as u')
        ->select('u.*', 'd.user_id', 'r.region_name')
        ->distinct()
        ->leftJoin('devices as d', 'u.id', '=', 'd.user_id')
        ->leftJoin('region as r', 'u.region_id', '=', 'r.region_id')
        ->whereNull('d.user_id')
        ->where('u.role',3)
        ->oldest('u.id')
        ->get();
```